# UIIView Inside UITableView Change Frame height to 0 or 60

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView in top of UITableView (drag and drop in storyboard . I tried to hide and show that view. but table view stands in place . how can i change frame of uivew so when it is invisible tableview goes all the way to top?

PS. I will provide more info for those who are willing to help. Thanks in Advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM3tA.png
 ![the view with hamburger button and textfield)

Comment: If you have set AutoLayout on then you need to set its constraint to change frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With autolayout:**

- Add height constraint to your UIView with button and textField
- Create Referencing Outlet for this height constraint (lets count it will be "searchViewHeightConstraint")
- Add Vertical Spacing Constraint between the UIView and the UITableView
- In code - when you need to hide UIView - just set its height constraint to 0

  `self.searchViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.f;`

Also you need to store somewhere the initial height of the UIView (when it is visible) and set its Height Constraint to this value when you need to show UIView.

**Without autolayout:**

- Save the value of UIView frame height
- Set the height of UIView to 0
- Decrease the y-coordinate of UITableView frame with saved height of UIView

  ```
  CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;    
  tableViewFrame.origin.y -= viewInitialHeight;    
  tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
  ```